# HTMLserviceで画像を表示するには？

Tags: google-apps-script

以下のようなコードを書きましたが、画像が表示されません。　何故でしょうか？
画像はマイドライブ下のGoogleフォトにあります。

コード.gs　側

```javascript
function getPic(idStr) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(idStr);   
  var imgTag = '';


  imgTag += '<p><img src="' + file.getBlob() + '" id="image-box" /></p>' 

  // file.getBlob() を　file.getUrl()　としても表示されません。
  return(imgTag);
}
```

showPic.html　側

```html
<input type ="button" value ="getPic" onclick ="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessImg).getPic('fileID_string')">  

function onSuccessImg(res){       
  var imgBox = document.getElementById("image-box"); 
  imgBox.innerHTML = res;        
}

<html>
<body>
   <p><img src="xxxx" id="image-box" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=GoogleDriveから見たファイルのID`

のURLであれば表示されるとおもいます

「Google Driveから見た」がキモです